# Copy file remotely with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing a *PowerShell* script that I want to run from Server A.
I want to connect to Server B and copy a file to Server A as a backup.

If that can't be done then I would like to connect to Server B from Server A and copy a file to another directory in Server B.

I see the [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Copy-Item) command, but I don't see how to give it a computer name.

I would have thought I could do something like

```
Copy-Item -ComputerName ServerB -Path C:\Programs\temp\test.txt -Destination (not sure how it would know to use ServerB or ServerA)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Simply use the administrative shares to copy files between systems.
It's much easier this way.

```
Copy-Item -Path \\serverb\c$\programs\temp\test.txt -Destination \\servera\c$\programs\temp\test.txt;
```

By using UNC paths instead of local filesystem paths, you help to
ensure that your script is executable from any client system with
access to those UNC paths. If you use local filesystem paths, then you
are cornering yourself into running the script on a specific computer.

Comment: One possible issue with this approach is that Copy-Item doesn't support alternate credentials (if you have to run the command with a different user). In that case, the New-PSDrive approach is required.

Comment: This solution only works if there is no firewall between the hosts blocking UNC shares. In that case the correct solution is below (`Copy-Item -FromSession`).

Comment: Admin shared do not always work, for example I cannot copy a file from or into a docker container but with Copy item it's possible if you enable with WINRM over SSH

Answer (score 125):

From **PowerShell version 5 onwards** (included in Windows Server 2016, [downloadable as part of WMF 5 for earlier versions](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=50395)), this is possible with remoting. The benefit of this is that it works even if, for whatever reason, you can't access shares.

For this to work, the local session where copying is initiated must have PowerShell 5 or higher installed. The remote session does *not* need to have PowerShell 5 installed -- it works with PowerShell versions as low as 2, and Windows Server versions as low as 2008 R2.<sup>[1]</sup>

From server A, create a session to server B:

```
$b = New-PSSession B
```

And then, still from A:

```
Copy-Item -FromSession $b C:\Programs\temp\test.txt -Destination C:\Programs\temp\test.txt
```

Copying items to B is done with `-ToSession`. Note that local paths are used in both cases; you have to keep track of what server you're on.

---

[1]: when copying from or to a remote server that only has PowerShell 2, beware of [this bug in PowerShell 5.1](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2469), which at the time of writing means recursive file copying doesn't work with `-ToSession`, an apparently copying doesn't work at all with `-FromSession`.

Comment: I have found it is not necessary for both servers to have PS 5 installed. I just performed a successful test where only the source server (Windows 10) had PS 5 installed. The target was Windows Server 2012 R2 with default PS installed ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion reports 4).

Comment: If you use -ToSession on the source, only the source needs PS 5 installed. If you use -FromSession on the target, only the target needs PS 5 installed.

Comment: This also works when you only have Hypervisor installed (without server), no need to set up shares just use the sessions!

Comment: Thank you! Nice, elegant solution, similar to `scp` over `ssh` on Linux... no need to bother with pesky shares!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I try to acchieve something similar: I work on PC A and want to copy files from PC B to PC C over LAN. Any Idea how to do this?

Comment: @Honduriel: use `Invoke-Command` to remote the copy command from A to B (or to C, depending on what direction you want to copy in). Or `Enter-PSSession` if you want to do it interactively.

Comment: This can be slow for big files.

Comment: Use absolution path for source file, otherwise you may see a `Only absolute paths are supported on remote copy operations` error

Answer (score 43):

Use `net use` or `New-PSDrive` to create a new drive:

**New-PsDrive:** create a new PsDrive only visible in PowerShell environment:

```
New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root \\ServerName\Share
Copy-Item BigFile Y:\BigFileCopy
```

**Net use:** create a new drive visible in all parts of the OS.

```
Net use y: \\ServerName\Share
Copy-Item BigFile Y:\BigFileCopy
```

Comment: If I run this twice I get `New-PSDrive : A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated` -> I think a previous session is still ongoing -> So I tried to use `Remove-PSDrive` -> still it doesn't work. Also `net use <driveLetter> /delete` didn't help. Any other thing I can do so I'm able to run this command in a software build configuration?

Comment: It has no sense to run `New-PSDrive` two times you should have `A drive with the name 'Y' already exists.`

Comment: I agree it makes no sense to run it twice. But it's incorporated into a build step and the build runs several times a day. So my approach was to remove the drive once I did the work I needed and I was assuming it would be no problem to recreate it once a new build execution happens. But it seems a problem though. Any other hint?

Comment: What about testing if it's mounted before mounting it ? or you can use  Remove-PSDrive in your script when you are sure that all handles  using this path are closed.

Answer (score 18):

Just in case that the remote file needs your credential to get accessed, you can generate a *System.Net.WebClient* object using cmdlet *New-Object* to "Copy File Remotely", like so

```
$Source = "\\192.168.x.x\somefile.txt"
$Dest   = "C:\Users\user\somefile.txt"
$Username = "username"
$Password = "password"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password)

$WebClient.DownloadFile($Source, $Dest)
```

Or if you need to upload a file, you can use UploadFile:

```
$Dest = "\\192.168.x.x\somefile.txt"
$Source   = "C:\Users\user\somefile.txt"

$WebClient.UploadFile($Dest, $Source)
```

Comment: @klm_ Can you please explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

**None** of the above answers worked for me. I kept getting this error:

```
Copy-Item : Access is denied
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\192.168.1.100\Shared\test.txt:String) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException>   
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

So **this** did it for me:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=yes
```

Then from my host my machine in the Run box I just did this:

```
\\{IP address of nanoserver}\C$
```

Comment: Chances are you ran into problems with share + filesystem permissions. Remember that the most restrictive permissions win, so even if you have access at the NTFS filesystem layer, if the share permissions restrict you, then you won't be able to write. :)

Comment: Copy files remotely using PowerShell. This does not answer the ops question

Comment: Thanks @Ken, I'll do my best to abide by rules next time.  Was hoping someone would benefit from the workaround, as PowerShell gave issues with permissions. 

Does StackOverflow not permit providing solutions where the offered solutions don't work?