# Hashing a remote file over a CIM Session (WMI). Not SMB

Tags: powershell, hash, wmi, md5

Goal: Calculate the MD5 Hash of a remote file using a CIM Session (not using SMB).

I want to hash a file on a remote windows system that is not sharing C$.  I can copy the remote file via a CIM session (so I know I can access the file), but when trying the code below I get the following error:

> Resolve-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'CIM_DataFile' does not exist

```
$ComputerName = "RemoteComputerName"
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerName

$files = Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CimSession -ClassName CIM_DataFile -Filter “Path = '\\Temp\\' AND Extension = 'exe'”

foreach ($file in $files) {
    # This works to copy the file, so I know I can access the file. I guess could
    # copy the file, then hash it... but I don't want to.
    #$newfile = “C:\Test2\$($file.FileName).$($file.Extension)”
    #Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $file  -MethodName Copy -Arguments @{Filename = $newfile}

    # This is where the errror occurs:
    # Resolve-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'CIM_DataFile' does
    # not exist.
    Get-FileHash -Path $file -Algorithm MD5
}
```

Comment: There are no CIM-classes that offer a md5-method AFAIK. And as you've discovered yourself, other non-CIM cmdlets doesn't support CIM-paths/-objects. Is it a Windows server? If so, you could use PSRemoting with `Invoke-Command` to find files and calculate md5. It uses the same protocol (WSMAN) as CimSession.

Comment: On recent versions of Windows, PowerShell remoting works out of the box and (on even more recent versions) it [directly supports remote file copying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741609/copy-file-remotely-with-powershell/39122508#39122508), requiring no SMB shares. As such it's much more convenient than CIM in most scenarios.