# How to transfer files (folders) from one server to another with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, file, server, file-transfer, transfer

I just started working with PowerShell and I want to know how to transfer files between a local server and a remote server. 
Currently I do not have Administrator access to either server (I know I'm going to need it), how do I target the Get cmdlt? Do I use a URL?

Comment: Did you read other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741609/copy-file-remotely-with-powershell) related questions before posting this question? Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's vital that you get up to speed on the topic. Take the time to jump over to [MS Virtual academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/getting-started-with-microsoft-powershell-8276)
or [MS Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/GetStartedPowerShell3)
or [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell)   and take a quick training course on the topic.

What you are asking for is covered in them as well as in the PowerShell Help files, which include examples on how to do this.

```
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Copy-Item).Parameters
Get-help -Name Copy-Item -Full
Get-help -Name Copy-Item -Online
Get-help -Name Copy-Item -Examples
```

> NAME
>       Copy-Item
>        SYNOPSIS
>       Copies an item from one location to another.
>
> ```
> Example 1: Copy a file to the specified directory
>
> PS C:\>Copy-Item "C:\Wabash\Logfiles\mar1604.log.txt" -Destination "C:\Presentation"
>
> This command copies the mar1604.log.txt file to the C:\Presentation directory. The command does not delete the original
> ```
>
> file.
>       Example 2: Copy the contents of a directory to another directory
>
> ```
> PS C:\>Copy-Item "C:\Logfiles" -Destination "C:\Drawings" -Recurse
>
> This command copies the entire contents of the Logfiles directory into the Drawings directory. If the LogFiles directory contains files
> ```
>
> in 
>       subdirectories, those subdirectories will be copied with their file trees intact. The Container parameter is set to true by default.
>   This preserves

```
# Get parameter that accepts pipeline input
Get-Help Copy-Item -Parameter * | 
Where-Object {$_.pipelineInput -match 'true'} | 
Select * 


# Get cmdlet / function parameter aliases
(Get-Command Copy-Item).Parameters.Values | 
where aliases | 
select Name, Aliases | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Alias results for a given cmdlet or function.'
```