# PS Script to install software from remote domain share

Tags: powershell

I am working on creating a PowerSell script to install software from a remote share located on a different domain that requires authentication.
So, from a target server if I try browsing to remote domain share, I have to type in username/password (from remote domain) to authenticate.

Is there a way to account for this authentication in PowerShell?
Would I be using PSCredential for this purpose?

My script would copy the files from remote share to a local computer and then run the installers

```
Param{
   [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]   
      [String]$RemoteShare="\\remote.domain\share"
}

$Localfolder = "C:\temp"
$Software1 = "Examplesoftware.exe"

Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $RemoteShare -Childpath $Software1) -Destination $Localfolder
```

error:

```
WARNING: , System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException
WARNING: Cannot find path '\\remote.domain\share\Examplesoftware.exe' because it does not exist.
```

Thank you

Comment: Try to create a `New-PSSession` and then connect to the remote computer.

Comment: Please paste the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First enable PSRemoting:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

Afterwards, create a new PS session:

```
New-PSSession -Session $session -Credential Domain01\User01
```

And finally you can try something like this:

```
Copy-Item -FromSession $session C:\Programs\temp\test.txt -Destination C:\Programs\temp\test.txt
```

Here are two informative links:

[PowerShell explained - PS remoting](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-04-22-Powershell-installing-remote-software/#installing-from-a-remote-location)

[PSRemoting](https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)

[Copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741609/copy-file-remotely-with-powershell)

Comment: Thank you Alex. But wouldn't that be running the installer on the remote server? I am trying to do the opposite: run the script on a local server that retrieves the installers from a remote domain share to execute locally

Comment: @Norskyi, I edit a new command. Try to use `Copy-Item` with the `-FromSession` parameter. If it does not work, please show the screenshot and ensure the issue is not with your credential or a simple path error.

Comment: Thank toy Alex, that worked! I know this is a stretch but is there a way to use current/logged-in user's password as to avoid the login prompt? The username and passwords match accros the domains.

Comment: Also, can I make it work with UNC instead of "C:\Pro..." ?

Comment: @Norskyi, You could try to install the `CredentialManager` module from PSGallery. That enables you to access your Microsoft Credential Manager. I have personally not used it extensively but it could be worth a shot. What is the error when you use UNC?

Comment: I haven't tried UNC yet, your solution is working for me well enough, so I'll leave it as that. Thanks for the suggestion to use CredentialManager. Sadly, this is not going to work since I will be using this script from different servers.